# Publication/Escape and Encapsulation in Java

Tags: java, encapsulation

I'm reading the "Java Concurrency in Practice" book and there is a part that I don't quite understand. I know is an old book, and probably is the reason why there is no mention of my doubt.

In the "Sharing object" chapter there is a the section called "**Publication and escape**":

> Publishing an object means making it available to code outside of its
>   current scope, such as by storing a reference to it where other code
>   can find it, returning it from a nonprivate method, or passing it to a
>   method in another class ...
>
> An object that is published when it
>   should not have been is said to have escaped.

And there is an example:

```
class UnsafeStates
{
   private String[] states = new String []
   {"AK", "AL" ....};

   public String [] getStates(){return states;}
}
```

> Publishing states in this way is problematic because any caller can
>   modify its contents. In this case, the states array has escaped its
>   intend scope, because what was supposed to be private state has been
>   effectively made public.

And is specified to don't do **never** in this way.

I suddendly thought about the encapsulation concept where, basically, say to do exactly this.

I misunderstood the concepts or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this method:

```
public String [] getStates(){return states;}
```

Return your reference to `states` array.

Even though you declare `states` as private but if you get it via `getStates()` method, you still can modify the `states` variable:

```
UnsafeStates us = new UnsafeStates();
String[] copyStates = us.getStates();
copyStates[0] = "You don't know"; // Here the change to `copyStates` also affect the `states` variable since they're both reference to the same array.
```

Normally, for objects and array properties, you often return a deep copy of that properties to prevent modify internal properties.

Ex: For array:

```
String[] copied = new String[states.length];
System.arraycopy(states, 0, copied, 0, states.length);
return copied;
```

For List:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(internalList);
```

For Object:

```
return internalObject.clone(); // Require deep clone
```

Comment: After your answer I was reading this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006824/how-to-encapsulate-an-array-in-java. So, in the book, basically the important point is that you can modify the contents of the array (object) outside its intended scope. Thank you.